# Selecting specific row from a column from 'Data Source' in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I found an error with a specific row on my tableau visualization. I would like to identify that row. The error seems to be made once my Excel file is loaded into Tableau. Is there a way I could do a sort of 'Control F' or 'Command F' to find this specific row? Any help would be great!

Comment: You can export your data from Tableau an view back in excel if you'd like
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/save_export_data.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know which column the mistake is, you can do a quick filter on the column. Then click on the black upside down triangle on the top right of the quick filter window. Tableau supports a Wildcard Match filter which is similar to Find in that you can type in a value.

[image]

Comment: I went about it slightly different, but it worked in the end. Thank you!